# Simple Spark app running slow on 3 gb of data

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, emr

Spark is running slow.
I have 3 GB of data total (six .csv files). 30 millions of records.
I try to run simple Spark app on Elastic Map Reduce AWS cluster (EMR).
But performance is very slow.

I need to do some operations on all this 30 millions records:
- Filter them into 4 groups.
- For each group calculate some metric, see **getTotalOps()** method

I measured the time, and I took me around 15 minutes to run this part of code. I don't count towards this 15 minutes time to read the data from file and create JavaRDD out of it.

```
 // Read data from 6 files and create one JavaRDD from those files:

   JavaRDD<PurchasesDataObject> allRecords = context.textFile(inputFilePath).map (
                    data -> {
                        String[] fields = data.split(",");
                        return new PurchasesDataObject(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3],fields[4]);                       
                    });


    // Filter all records into 4 groups:
JavaRDD<PurchasesDataObject> collectionControl = allRecords.filter(record -> "C".equals(record.getTreatmentName()));

JavaRDD<PurchasesDataObject> collectionTreatment = allRecords.filter(record -> "T1".equals(record.getTreatmentName()));

JavaRDD<PurchasesDataObject> collectionControlNW = collectionControl.filter(record ->{ return webLabSessionVideoWatchedList.get(record.getSessionId()) == null ? true : false; });

JavaRDD<PurchasesDataObject> collectionControlW = collectionControl.filter(record -> {return webLabSessionVideoWatchedList.get(record.getSessionId()) != null ? true : false;});

// Calculate metrics:
    double totalOpsControl = getTotalOps(collectionControl);
    double totalOpsTreatment = getTotalOps(collectionTreatment);
    double totalOpsControlNW = getTotalOps(collectionControlNW);
    double totalOpsControlW = getTotalOps(collectionControlW);

// .... Output results





private double getTotalOps(JavaRDD<PurchasesDataObject> dataCollection) {
        return dataCollection
                .mapToDouble(data -> data.getPrice() * data.getQuantity())
                .sum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
allRecords.cache
```

Perform the cache before doing different actions on the same data. So it will not repeatedly read it from Disk or S3.

Answer (score 1):

.cache() would help, but Spark is slow, so 15 minutes for 30 million rows is an OK performance for Spark.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting cache(). Could you explain please why it's slow? I was recommended to use Spark for my use case. But now it's seems like It would be faster to perform all calculations witout Spark, using pure Java and Java8. 

My use case is calculate 10-15 metrics (like you saw in my code below) on dataset (3-5 GB of data). If time for one metric was 15 minutes, do you think is Ok to wait 15*10 = 150 minutes to get 10 metrics like I calculated above? [metrics like avrg, sum, avg with group by etc.]

Comment: Spark is a complex machine written in Java and Scala. It's main purpose  is to use HDFS and parallel processing to work with large amount of data. If you can fit the data into memory, there's no reason to use Spark.